# Monte Carlo Simulation of a date based on another date

Tags: r, random, dplyr, simulation, montecarlo

I have a dataset like this. The date_e was accurate for status= "1". I want to simulate date_e based on age. Therefore, new_date_e will be changed for status="0", will be same for status="1". Also, status=1 has higher risk, so df= date_e-age should be in average shorter for status="1"than "0".

```
           age      date_e  status  id
1   1950-10-21 2008-11-02      0   1
2   1941-02-11 2006-08-28      0   2
3   1940-01-20 2000-05-25      0   3
4   1957-11-05 2008-03-28      1   4
5   1946-09-15 2004-03-10      0   5
```

and the data is :

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

age <- sample(seq(as.Date('1930-01-01'), as.Date('1970-01-01'), by="day"), 1000)
date1 <- sample(seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2010-01-01'), by="day"), 1000)
status <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
df <- data.frame(age, date1, status)
df <- df %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output? Also, when simulating data, please include a call to `?set.seed` before calling pseudo-RNG functions.

Comment: @Ali Roghani, I am sorry but the question is totally unclear. What does it mean " new_date_e will be changed for status="0", will be same for status="1"" ? Changed how? What do you mean "higher risk"? If you need help you must absolutely give more details and much more explanations.

Comment: Hello, I mean when you make a new column based on data_e, you will call it new_date_e, which has the same date by date_e for sataus="1", while we will use simulated dates for status="0". Regarding higher risk,  I assumed that people with higher age has higher risk so they sholud have an earlier date_e  (hospitalization), also status=1 will have more risk than status=1, so df1= date_e(1)-age(e) for the status=1 is smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are wanting to simulate is the effect of `status` on longevity (i.e. the time difference between `date1` and `age` in your reproducible example). At the moment, `status` has no effect on longevity:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
ggplot(aes(x    = factor(status), 
           y    = as.numeric(difftime(date1, age, unit = 'w'))/52,
           fill = factor(status))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.6) +
  guides(fill = guide_none()) +
  labs(x = 'Status', y = 'Age (years)')
```

[image]

Effectively, what you need to do is to subtract a random amount of time from the `date1` column where `status == 1`. To do this, you can take advantage of the fact that dates are stored as integers 'under the hood' in R, and the fact that you can multiply a random draw by the `status` column, since those with `status == 0` will thereby always have 0 subtracted.

So the answer is that you only need do:

```r
df$date1 <- df$date1 - df$status * round(rnorm(nrow(df), 3650, 500))
```

Which will remove on average 10 years from those with `status == 1` but leave those with `status == 0` as-is:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x    = factor(status), 
             y    = as.numeric(difftime(date1, age, unit = 'w'))/52,
             fill = factor(status))) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.6) +
  guides(fill = guide_none()) +
  labs(x = 'Status', y = 'Age (years)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is great help, but your date_1 in all cases is coming down, while I think it is better that a part of those have a higher date, and mostly have a lower date.